# PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT utf 8 encoding

Tags: pdo, persistent-connection

I set `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true`, but show my text with other encoding!

```
Ù‡Ù…Ø±Ø§Ù‡ Ø³ÙˆØ±Ø§Ù† Ø¨Ø§Ø´ÛŒØ¯ Ø¯Ø±
```

Please help me out

```
// This is not helpful : `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',` 
// my default encoding in phpmyadmin is utf8-general
```