# PHP PDO ,Can't set name while connection is persistant?

Tags: php, database, pdo, utf-8, character-encoding

This is a part of my PDO class. I need to use `utf-8` for Hebrew language but when i set `ATTR_PERSISTENT` to `true` the output text will be shown like `??????` If I switch the `ATTR_PERSISTENT` to `false` the output will be right.

```
public function __construct() {
    // Set DSN
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
    // Set options
    $options = array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>  'SET NAMES utf8',
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
    );
    // Create a new PDO instanace
    try {
        $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
    }
    // Catch any errors
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Is there any conflict between:

```
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>  'SET NAMES utf8'
```

And:

```
PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
```

Comment: What are the encode type of file?

Comment: What is curious, is that it was [asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29714253/pdoattr-persistent-utf-8-encoding) and caught almost no attention.

Comment: Did you try setting the `charset` directly into the connection string? Like `dbname=' . $this->dbname;charset=utf8`?

Comment: [Found one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475548/pdo-mysql-and-broken-utf-8-encoding), see if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042474/pdo-connection-utf-8-declaration-with-set-names-character-set) .

Setting it in DSN is the only proper way, so i changed the code to this :

```
 public function __construct() {
        // Set DSN
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname .';charset=utf8';
        // Set options
        $options = array(
            //PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>  "SET NAMES utf8",
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
        );
        // Create a new PDO instanace
        try {
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        }
        // Catch any errors
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

And now the output is right.

Comment: Glad to see it helped :)